# gdlib-config Ubuntu 16.04 / Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

Sorry for the cross post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036228/gdlib-config-ubuntu-16-04-ubuntu-18-04) but I think it fit better here.

I'm on a W10 Host using VirtualBox. I had set up two virtual environments :  Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying to install the GD perl module. For this I need the gdlib-config file.

I'm able to get it with Ubuntu 16.04 using the following :

```
$whereis gdlib-config
gdlib-config:
$sudo apt-get install libgd-dev
$whereis gdlib-config
gdlib-config: /usr/bin/gdlib-config /usr/share/man/man1/gdlib-config.1.gz
```

Same command lines under Ubuntu 18.04 :

```
$whereis gdlib-config
gdlib-config:
$sudo apt-get install libgd-dev
$whereis gdlib-config
gdlib-config:
```

Both libgd-dev installations ends successfully

Where can I get the gdlib-config for Ubuntu 18.04 ? Why did they remove gdlib-config file from the libgd-dev library ?

Thanks

Comment: It's been missing even in 17.10. The changelog for `libgd-dev` (`apt-get changelog libgd-dev > temp.txt`) has this:   `* Don't install obsolete gdlib-config`.

Comment: How am I suppose to build GD-2.56 without this file ?

    ~/GD-2.56$/usr/bin/perl Build.PL --installdirs site

    **UNRECOVERABLE ERROR**
    Could not find gdlib-config in the search path. Please install libgd 2.0.28 or higher

I'm already libgd-dev : 2.2.5-4

Comment: *How* are you "trying to install the GD perl module"? you shouldn't need to build it from source (there is a binary package `libgd-perl`). If you **really** need to build a version that needs `gdlib-config`, then it really doesn't do anything that `pkg-config gdlib` can't be made to do - you *could* write your own shell wrapper for `pkg-config` (but I don't believe it really should be necessary).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04, with GD-2.56, drop the obsolete check warning by the option `--ignore_missing_gd` would work after installing the `libgd` libraries with `apt`.

i.e.

```
sudo apt install libgd-dev libgd-perl
perl Makefile.PL --ignore_missing_gd
```